# What permissions do I need to use the SHOW TABLE command in Teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata

What permissions do I need to use the `SHOW TABLE` command in Teradata?

I've looked in the Teradata Data Dictionary, the Teradata Administrator User Guide and searched on Google, but I can't find any documentation for this.

I'm getting the error:

> The user does not have any access to xxx.yyy

Comment: "tell me nothing"? it must show some error

Comment: Yeah, it show error: The user does not have any access to xxx.yyy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **SHOW** privilege, available at the table level and database level, allows a user to see the
table definition and access DCL statements (such as **SHOW TABLE, HELP TABLE, HELP
STATS**, and so on) without having **SELECT** access to a table.
Grant the **SHOW** privilege to a developer or service personnel to allow access to information
about an object and see the structure, but not have any actual access to any of the data.
Any user with the **"WITH GRANT"** option can grant the **SHOW** privilege to others.

The following is the syntax to grant show table on a single table to a user.

```
GRANT SHOW ON TableName TO UserName
```

The following is the syntax to grant show table for all the tables in a database to a user.

```
GRANT SHOW ON DatabaseName TO UserName
```

Comment: OK, it works. But what if I want grant show to all schemas/tables?

Comment: Use database name instead of table name

Comment: @emaillenin yeah it works, but still I can grant show to only one database/table. When I create new schemas, I must grant SHOW permission again ;/ How can I do it for all schemas (including new schemas/tables)?

Comment: If you introduce a stored procedure to manage the creation of your databases then you can bundle in additional statements such as including the SHOW privilege on the newly created database to a ROLE that manages all of your SHOW privileges for a collection of users. Then you can also include the DUMP, RESTORE privileges for your ARC users' role and privileges for your admins on the tables contained within the database.

Comment: @emaillenin 1 question: I see I can also grant select privilege to show table:
GRANT SELECT ON DBC TO user;
but what table in DBC? I don't want grant select to all tables in DBC. So what table? Is it TextTbl?

Comment: @emaillenin Nvm problem resolved. I need to grant select privilege to: dbc.TVM, dbc.Dbase and dbc.TextTbl :)